# Changes to be done in Android application to put it in Galaxy tab

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to put my Android application in a Galaxy tab. When I installed the app, the resolution of the UI of my application changed. But it's looking good in emulator and other Android 2.2 phones. But in Galaxy tab, the resolution is changed. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galaxy Tab has a pixel density of about 170. That isn't all that different from an mdpi device. (However, Android market apparently classifies it as an hdpi device.)

Are you sure that the problem is with the resolution? It's an extra large screen; perhaps that's causing problems?

Comment: yes.. extra large screen is the problem. How can i resolve that

Comment: See my answer to a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881773/how-to-make-my-app-full-screen-on-galaxy-tab/4881852#4881852

Answer (score 1):

I suggest getting device's (Samsung Galaxy Tab) height-width then optimise your resources according to them. Try to find out whether they lie in hdpi/mdpi or ldpi range

You may be required to use new set of graphics for them.

Comment: i have to put the application in other phones too ..changing the height and width may affect that.. Large screen of galaxy tab is the problem for me.. How can i resolev that /..Pls help

Comment: I understand your situation, are you using different resources for hdpi/mdpi/ldpi ?  What combinations of layouts are you using? are you fixing positions with 'px' ?